# Difference between returning a parent type or child type

Tags: java, interface, return-type

I was wondering (and pardon if this is a repeat question, but I could not find information specifically regarding my question) what the difference between defining a method as returning a parent type or child type. Here is my specific scenario:

Imagine the following classes and interface:

```
public interface Color{
    public int getRedVal();
    public int getGreenVal();
    public int getBlueVal();
}
public class RGBColor implements Color{
    public int getRedVal() {...}
    public int getGreenVal() {...}
    public int getBlueVal() {...}
}
public class HSVColor implements Color{
    public int getRedVal() {...}
    public int getGreenVal() {...}
    public int getBlueVal() {...}
}
```

Now, if I were to include a method called `getRGB()`, what would be the difference between:

```
public Color getRGB() {return new RGBColor();}
```

and

```
public RGBColor getRGB() {return new RGBColor();}
```

I can't seem to find documentation regarding this, and I'm sure it's a simple answer. Either way, thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Color getRGB() { return new RGBColor(); }
```

Up-casting is here (casting to a supertype). You are working on more abstract level not thinking about implementation (what is good) and can use only parent's methods.

```
public RGBColor getRGB() { return new RGBColor(); }
```

You and your architecture are tightly bound to the implementation (`RGBColor`), but can use specific methods defined in this subclass.

*I would prefer the first option rather than the second one.*

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make your factory methods static.

Second, the difference between the two methods is the declared return type. If you used the first of the two definitions, a programmer would write:

```
Color c = getRGB();  // this is legal
```

They could not write:

```
RGBColor c = getRGB();  // This is illegal
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not much difference if you've coded to your interface correctly. However, the difference is simply the reference type.

Suppose `RGBColor` had an additional public method:

```
public int[] getRGBFormatVals() //I dunno; I made it up!
```

You would not be able to invoke this method on an instance you obtained from a return type `Color`, but you could if you used return type `RGBColor`. To restate my previous point, this is unlikely to occur if you've coded to your interface properly.

Since your method is called `getRGB`, I would recommend returning an `RGBColor`, because that's all that should return from a method with such a name. You could just as easily assign it to a `Color` reference though to have the same effect and see the result.